# How to fit IconButton size in Row in flutter web? Icon size renders outside the row view

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm making a portfolio with flutter web. I created iconButtons of social handles. But when I tried to click on the iconButtons, the padding was not right.

I tried to fix it with add padding, separated row, but it didn't work out.
You can see the below image for reference of what I'm trying to say.
[click here to see the web view debug paint image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKOXw.png)

This is the row widget in which I added these iconButtons-

```
   class IntroductionRow extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 90.0,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          ContactIcon(iconData: FontAwesomeIcons.github, onPress: kLaunchGithubURL,),
          // SizedBox(width: 30.0,),
          ContactIcon(iconData: FontAwesomeIcons.linkedin, onPress: kLaunchLinkedInURL,),
          // SizedBox(width: 30.0,),
          ContactIcon(iconData: Icons.mail, onPress: kLaunchMailURL,),
          // SizedBox(width: 30.0,),
          ContactIcon(iconData: FontAwesomeIcons.telegram, onPress: kLaunchTelegramURL, ),
          // SizedBox(width: 30.0,),
          ContactIcon(iconData: FontAwesomeIcons.code, onPress: kLaunchLeetCodeURL,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


//This is the widget of iconButton- 
class ContactIcon extends StatelessWidget {

  final IconData iconData;
  final Function onPress;
  final bool isMobile;

  ContactIcon({@required this.iconData, this.onPress, this.isMobile = false});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
      hoverColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        focusColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        icon:
        Center(
          child: Icon(
              iconData,
              size: isMobile ? 30.0 : 60.0 ,
              color: Colors.white),
        ),
        onPressed: onPress);
  }
}
```

I recently started flutter, that's why I don't know much about all widgets-
please let me know if you find any other mistake.

Comment: You should include the code of your `Row` and its children so we can see the exact widget layout.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution of my problem. I just need to add the constraints in my IconButton

constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 80, height: 80),

and also instead of padding, I had to use sizedBox.